# I want to get auto-generated channel's information (music, sports...) using YouTube API v3

Tags: api, youtube, auto-generate

I've got their channel's ID, playlist ID and playlistItem's ID. But the result is different from what I saw in YouTube page.

How can I get Korean auto-generated channel information?

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=id,snippet,contentDetails&channelId={channel id} -> playlist ID

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,status&playlistId={playlist} -> playlistitem ID

It worked well except YouTube auto-generated channels.

Plaese help..